# AWS Lambda SAM, specify multiple policies

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-cloudformation

I have the following AWS SAM file (showing extract) for a lambda function.  The problem is that I'm trying to specify multiple policies and this does not work, I get an error

```
Resources:
  Get:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: fnStores
      Handler: handler.get
      Runtime: nodejs6.10
      Policies: 
        -AmazonDynamoDBReadOnlyAccess
        -AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess
```

This is the error I get

**"ARN -AmazonDynamoDBReadOnlyAccess -AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess is not valid.**

On a side note, is it possible to create a custom policy that combines the above  two and then use that?  If so please provide an example.

Comment: The list under `Policies` isn'y valid YAML. Add a space between `-` and `AmazonDynamoDBReadOnlyAccess`

Answer (score 6):

The YAML list isn't valid.  Need a space between `-` and the Policy names

Try

```
Resources:
  Get:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: fnStores
      Handler: handler.get
      Runtime: nodejs6.10
      Policies: 
        - AmazonDynamoDBReadOnlyAccess
        - AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess
```